# Why does my java program crashes?

Tags: java

My program compiles and runs correctly but after the execution, my program crashes.

[image]

Below is my code:

```
public class Hi 
{
    public static void main (String[]args) 
        {
        System.out.println("Hi");

        }
}
```

Can anyone help me regarding this... thanks.

Comment: which java sdk are you using? There were problems in old jdks... if you are using old... get the latest one and try again...

Comment: It might sound weird, but I faced the same when I use "ant". The trick I used - use the complete path to javac  [eg -  c:\java\bin\javac ] and try again !

Comment: Its because you are saying `Hi`. Try saying `Hello World`. That might fix it. ;P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not your program that crashed, it's `javac`, i.e. the compiler itself. Something's terribly wrong with your Java installation (or your system itself) - try re-installing it.

Comment: Beware: *JDK* installation, not necessarily the *JRE* installation.

Comment: Possibly there are pieces of two different versions of the Java SDK intermingled. You should uninstall all, and reinstall the current version (1.6.0_22 as of this writing)

Answer (score 1):

The command javac itself is failing means, its not even compiled... problem is definitely at JDK installation, you may have installed a wrong arch or for wrong platform. If it is right, try reinstalling it again and make sure your installation path has no spaces in it

Answer (score 0):

It compiles without any problem and runs fine. The thing is, that program is just fine and nothing should be going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I rarely used javac (prefer eclipse or netbeans for running C code.

As they said, its doesn't seem to be your code, but Javac

if there was a problem with your file or code it would print a log.

try reinstalling java jdk